# ¿ Como capturar el id de una consulta y enviarlo a otra vista a un campo de texto usando C# MVC ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mvc

DISCULPEN MUCHACHOS, me podrian por favor ayudar tengo una tabla en un modal en donde quiero capturar el id y enviarlo a un campo de text para hacer un registro de datos, a continuacion les muestro lo que necesito:

[image: boton modal]

[image: modal]

este es el codigo

Crear Nuevo

accedemos al boton que arroja el modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id=myinput data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="@Url.Action("ConsultaProducto","Pedidos")">
                    Seleccionar Producto
</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <!--Content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">



                
    </div>
```

tabla donde quiero capturar los datos para enviarlos a un cuadro de texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo para confirmar, necesitas mandar el id que seleccionas del modal a otra vista?

Comment: exacto @luis necesito desde el modal capturar el id, y enviarlo a otra vista, esta vista debe registrar los datos de un producto, como podria hacerlo podrian ayudarme por favor, debo enviar el id a una vista que ya existe.